# Python Pandas Average by Location and Date/Month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using: Python 3.6, Pandas 0.22

I have a .csv file that I need to get an average from based on the month, and location. This is one line from the data, there are many more with multiple locations and dates:

`NAME   DATE    SNOW
GRAND RAPIDS GERALD R FORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, MI US 1/1/2016, 0.7`

So far I have successfully sorted the info based on the month, and average per month:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

gname = df2.groupby('NAME')

for NAME,  NAME_df2 in gname:
    df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])
    df2.groupby(df2['DATE'].dt.strftime('%B'))['SNOW'].mean().sort_values()
```

When executed:

```
  DATE
August       0.000000
July         0.000000
June         0.000000
September    0.000000
May          0.000562
October      0.000966
November     0.019712
April        0.155592
March        0.248475
February     0.319048
January      0.622969
December     1.129986
Name: SNOW, dtype: float64
```

My issue is that this code is just giving the total average of every month at all the locations in an endless loop. I cannot figure out how to get my output to sort the data based on average snowfall at each location, per month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You modify the DataFrame in the loop as you iterate through it. This is wrong.

You need to group by both month and location:

```
df2.groupby([df.DATE.dt.month,'NAME']).mean()
```

You will get a DataFrame with a two-level multiindex. You can later convert it to a table by `unstack()`ing.

Comment: Are you suggesting I remove the `.sort_values()`? The reason I thought I needed that was because my next step from here is to write to a new .csv file which contains the headers `NAME, MONTH, AVERAGE`.

Comment: No, I am not suggesting that. The answer does not depend on whether you remove it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the average of a `df` numerical column, called `df['Sentiment']`, monthly and for every Place specified in the column `'Place'`:

#### 0. Import the `datetime` module:

```
    from datetime import datetime
```

#### 1. The Data frame

Generate a DataFrame with columns `'date'`, `'Sentiment'`, `'Place'`:

```
    date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='3/05/2018', freq='W')
    df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
    df['Sentiment']=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
    df['Place']=['home']*3 + ['With friends']*3 + ['School']*3
    print(df)



            date  Sentiment         Place
    0 2018-01-07         62          home
    1 2018-01-14         55          home
    2 2018-01-21         84          home
    3 2018-01-28         65  With_friends
    4 2018-02-04          3  With_friends
    5 2018-02-11         26  With_friends
    6 2018-02-18          9        School
    7 2018-02-25         52        School
    8 2018-03-04         74        School
```

#### 2. Convert the `'date'`column into the index of the `df`: And then retrieve the *month* list fro the index:

```
    df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
    months=df.index.month



                Sentiment         Place
    date                               
    2018-01-07         64          home
    2018-01-14         41          home
    2018-01-21         97          home
    2018-01-28         44  With_friends
    2018-02-04         37  With_friends
    2018-02-11         69  With_friends
    2018-02-18         15        School
    2018-02-25         42        School
    2018-03-04          4        School
```

#### 3. Calculate the mean by groups: months and `'Place'`:

```
    monthly_val=df.groupby([months,'Place']).mean()



                       Sentiment
    date Place                  
    1    With_friends  44.000000
         home          67.333333
    2    School        28.500000
         With_friends  53.000000
    3    School         4.000000
```

#### 4. unstack()

As **@DYZ** suggested above you can unstack monthly_val to get an informative cross tab table:

```
    monthly_val.unstack()



          Sentiment                   
    Place    School With_friends  home
    date                              
    1           NaN         65.0  67.0
    2          30.5         14.5   NaN
    3          74.0          NaN   NaN
```